# How we can notify parent window about an occurrence of clicked event in button child class?

Tags: qt

I am using mouse press event and clicked event in button class. How I can notify the parent window about the occurrence of this event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to connect the signal `clicked()` of your button to a slot in your parent class (your question is not so clear).

If you want to pass the click coordinates to the parent, connect the `clicked()` event to an private slot in your button class, and emit a custom `clicked(QPoint)` signal with the mouse coordinate (`mapFromGlobal(QCursor::pos())`) as parameter, and connect that signal in a slot in the parent.

PS: A mouse press event and a click event are not the same thing: if the mouse moves after the press event but before the release event, this is not a click anymore.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but actually i want when i press the button a new window should open and as long as the window is opened the button should be in pressed state and when i close that window the button should come in the released state. Here actually i am using different images for pressed and released state. So how i can keep that button in pressed state as long as the new window is opened.

Comment: so set the button's checkable property to true and that keeps the button clicked until you click it again. And when your window closes emit signal to click the button again

Comment: @user Please update your question with this clarification rather than post as an answer. SO is not a traditional internet forum: you can edit your posts.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use [parentWidget](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qwidget.html#parentWidget)().

Call parentWidget()->mousePressEvent(event) to invoke the parentwidget for the same event